# How to insert columns in sub-tables for a grouped dataframe in `DataFrames.jl`?

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

What I want to do is:

- Group a data-frame by column ("col1") in `DataFrames.jl`, call it `grouped_df`
- Send the sub-tables from the `grouped_df` to a user defined function

  - The user-defined function will transform an existing column and should add a new column with relevant data

I want to transform an old column and add a new column in the same function because both action depend on basically same compute that is recoreded slightly differently.

```
function apply_scan_difference(df::AbstractDataFrame,ref_scan::Float64)
    
    current_scan::Float64 = calculate_current_scan(df)
    
    scan_difference::Float64 = current_scan - ref_scan
    
    df.scan = df.scan .- scan_difference

    insertcols!(df, ncol(df)+1, :shift .= scan_difference ) # `scan_difference` has already been calculated and being able to record it here would be efficient,right`
    
    return df::AbstractDataFrame
end
```

As you can see `scan_difference` is calculated for each group and is applied to the old column `scan` but I also want to record it for each group. Mentally, it feels like being able to do this in the same function would be the more effiecient way to do it.

But when I `combine(sdf -> apply_scan_different(sdf, ref_scan), grouped_df)` I get this error: `MethodError: no method matching ndims(::Type{Symbol})`

I tried changing the function to

```
function apply_scan_difference(df::AbstractDataFrame,ref_scan::Float64)
    
    current_scan::Float64 = calculate_current_scan(df)
    
    scan_difference::Float64 = current_scan - ref_scan
    
    df.scan = df.scan .- scan_difference

    insertcols!(df, ncol(df)+1, :shift => fill(scan_difference, nrow(df))) # `scan_difference` has already been calculated and being able to record it here would be efficient,right`
    
    return df::AbstractDataFrame
end
```

And called the function as `transform(sdf -> apply_scan_different(sdf, ref_scan), grouped_df)` but that produces this error

`ArgumentError: Column shift is already present in the data frame which is not allowed when` makeunique=true  and only applies the new column data to one group (looks like the first group).

I do not fully understand what it means to set makeunique=false`.

What is the right way to do this in Julia `DataFrames.jl` or does this goes against the grain and is not advisable?

Answer (score 1):

The groups produced by `groupby` are merely views into the original DataFrame. If you add a column to one, it necessarily adds a column to the whole DataFrame. Then, `insertcols` errors when it tries to insert `:shift` into a DataFrame that already has it (since [it has `makeunique=false` by default](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.insertcols!)).

To fix this you can either copy `sdf` so that changes aren't propagated to the parent DataFrame, or insert an empty `:shift` column first and then assign in place with `sdf[:, :shift] .= scan_difference`.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Bogumił Kamiński on the Julia discourse here https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-insert-columns-in-sub-tables-for-a-grouped-dataframe-in-dataframes-jl/109713

The answer turned out to be

```
function apply_scan_difference(df::AbstractDataFrame,ref_scan::Float64)
    current_scan::Float64 = calculate_current_scan(df)
    scan_difference::Float64 = current_scan - ref_scan
    res_df = copy(df) # to dealias a data frame
    res_df.scan = df.scan .- scan_difference
    res_df.shift .= scan_difference # this assumes :shift column is not present in res_df yet
    return res_df
end
```

looks like `copy` inside a function is the way to go!